# ${x_{n + 1}} = r(1 - x_n^2)$, how to prove $\{ x_n^2\} $ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$\{ {x_n}\} $ is given by ${x_{n + 1}} = r(1 - x_n^2)$, for $0 < r < 1,x_0= 0$

If $r \le \frac{1}{2}$, let $p = \overline {\lim } {x_n},q = \underline {\lim } {x_n},$ then

$p = r(1 - q^2), q = r(1 - p^2)$ , $(p - q)(1 - r(p + q)) = 0$,

when $r \le \frac{1}{2}$, it's easy to find that $p = q$, then  $\{ {x_n}\} $ is convergent.

My question is what if  $r  >   \frac{1}{2}$, how to prove $\{ x_n\} $ is convergent?

Comment: Does it necessarily converge?

Comment: @Kenta I'm not sure...

Comment: @  Professor Vector   Could you please give me some hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit more complicated than I thought at first: for $0<r\le\sqrt{3}/2$, $x_n$ converges to $$p=q=\frac{\sqrt{4r^2+1}-1}{2r}.$$
For $\sqrt{3}/2<r<1$, we have $$p=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{2n+1}=\frac{1+\sqrt{4r^2-3}}{2r}$$
and $$q=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{2n}=\frac{1-\sqrt{4r^2-3}}{2r}.$$
Proof: It's clear that $f(x)=r\,(1-x^2)$ maps $[0,r]$ into itself, so $x_n\in[0,r]$ is bounded. Since $$x_{n+2}=f(f(x_n))$$ is a monotone increasing function of $x_n$, from  $x_0<x_2$ follows by induction that $x_{2n}$ is increasing, and from $x_3<x_1=r$ follows that $x_{2n+1}$ is decreasing. So the limits $p,q$ exist. Both must be solutions of the equation $$x-f(f(x))=0.$$ Since $x=f(x)$ implies $x=f(f(x))$, the polynomial $x-f(x)$ must be a divisor of $x-f(f(x))$, and indeed
$$x-f(f(x))=(x-f(x))(r^2\,x^2-r\,x+1-r^2).$$ For $r<\sqrt{3}/2$, the second factor doesn't have a zero in $[0,r]$, so $p=q$ must be a zero of the first factor. For $r>\sqrt{3}/2$, we have $q<p$, and since $x_0<q$, by monotony of $f(f(x))$ we see $x_{2n}<q$ for all $n$, so the limit must be the smaller value, $q$. In the same way, we see from $x_1=r>p$ that $x_{2n+1}>p$ for all $n$, so that's the limit of the odd terms. It's easy to see that the positive solution of $x-f(x)=0$ lies between $p$ and $q$ (because $q-f(q)=q-p<0$ and $p-f(p)=p-q>0$).
For $r=\sqrt{3}/2$, all three values coincide, i.e. that's a triple solution of $x-f(f(x))=0$, so $x_n$ converges, but (typical for multiple zeroes) *very* slowly.

Comment: I see. You have an excellent skill , and that's really great. Thank you so much!

Comment: @sraung Jo You're welcome. If you do that for decades, starting from last millenium, you can't possibly avoid getting something right. ;)